# How to run a SQL query command for Access from another SQL query command?

Tags: c#, database, datatable, dataset, oledbcommand

The problem is that I need to Execute a SQL command for a query on Access which I already have running perfectly.

```
using (OleDbConnection _Connn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Pos\POS_DB(" + _DS.sNumCaja + ").accdb"))

sSQL = 
    "SELECT Sum(tblVentasArticulos.Cantidad) AS SumOfCantidad, Sum(tblVentasArticulos.Precio) AS SumOfPrecio, qryDepartamentos.Departamento" + " " +
    "FROM qryDepartamentos RIGHT JOIN (tblVentasArticulos RIGHT JOIN tblVentas ON tblVentasArticulos.Folio = tblVentas.Folio) ON qryDepartamentos.idDepartamento = tblVentasArticulos.Dep" + " " +
    "GROUP BY qryDepartamentos.Departamento;";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, _Connn);
```

That piece of code works well, but inside the sSQL string, the "qryDepartamentos" is a query I made inside Access from a table on another Access DataBase. Is there a way of making the Query before and storing it inside a DataSet to use it as a variable for another SQL command? I tried something like this:

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT tblDepartamentos.* FROM tblDepartamentos", conn);

            conn.Open();

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            adapter.Fill(results);
            DataView dv = new DataView(results);                
        }
```

Now I don't know how to add or use the DataSet data inside the first sSQL command, in order to replace the "qryDepartamentos".

---

Thank you but I figured it'd be easier to use a function and giving the parameters so it would return a simple string. Thank You All! :)

Comment: Not too clear that mate, but you might find some value in using Linq, or if you want to stick to access tech. Set up database links, http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx#BM3